# How to change state of another object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good day. Could you say me how to access change state of some object on object click action from another object.

I have element Calculator which has set of Buttons and one Indicator. I wanna change Indicator's state on some Button clicked. For example increment indicator value if any button clicked;

```
<style>
#calculator table {
    padding: 5px;;
    border: ridge 3px;
}

#calculator table tr td {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-button, .nav-button button {
    width: 100%;
}

.calc-indicator {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.calc-indicator input {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 93%;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: right;
}
</style>


var Indicator = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            value: 0
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
                <div className="calc-indicator">
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value}/>
                </div>);
    }
});

var Button = React.createClass({

    buttonClicked: function () {
        // here I wanna update Indicators state and render Indicator
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
                <div className="nav-button" id={this.props.digit}
                     onClick={this.buttonClicked.bind(this, "nav-button")}>
                    <button>{this.props.digit}</button>
                </div>
        );
    }
});


var Calculator = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
                <div id="calculator">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="4">
                                <Indicator />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="MC"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="MR"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="M+"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="M"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="BS"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="CL"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="C"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="/"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="7"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="8"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="9"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="*"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="4"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="5"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="6"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="-"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="2"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="3"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="+"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2">
                                <Button digit="0"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="."/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Button digit="="/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
        );
    }
});
React.render(<Calculator />, document.body);
```

If you know how to make code better, please, post your variants.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Move the state from Indicator to the Calculator. In the Button Class trigger this.props.add that is located in Calculator. So you have one Parent (Calculator) and 2 Childs (Button, Indicator).

Send the state down to the children

```js
<Button add={this.add} /> and <Indicator value={this.state.value} />
```